# Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path "/path/to/android/studio"

Tags: android, flutter

Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path "/path/to/android/studio".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG8Ko.png)

Please verify that the path is correct and update it by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir
''
To have flutter search for Android Studio installations automatically, remove
the configured path by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir

and i installed android studio

what is the solution for this error ??????

Comment: Run "flutter config". What's after "Settings:" ?

Comment: Please don't post terminal output (thus text) in a screenshot. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

Comment: You have the default path set as "/path/to/android/studio". This variable needs to be set to, you guessed it, the path to android studio.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed android studio, as i concerned flutter can not found path to android studio